# Sendmail, MTA, stolen passwords, and authentication logs

Tags: sendmail

I've got a Linux server (2.6.22) that's running sendmail.  And someone is managing to successfully use my server, to send out their spam.

Infuriating.

I can see in /var/log/secure that the server's various accounts are being constantly brute-forced for passwords, so I assume someone got a keypair at some point.  I've changed passwords for every account I can find, to nasty unknowable things.

I've checked to ensure sendmail isn't just relaying: rather, I'm seeing /var/spool/clientmqueue get filled with enormous amounts of spam.  Somebody is actually convincing my server to send mail on their behalf.

So, the main question is: what do I need to do to stop this?

Comment: Can you show some lightly sanitized logs and config? It's pretty hard to say what the problem is without them.

Answer (score 0):

Bruteforcing is standard operating procedure on basically any service open to the Internet these days. I would suggest installing fail2ban or a similar program and configuring it to monitor the logs for incorrect password attempts (at least for SSH and for your mailserver) and blacklist IPs (via iptables) which make several bad attempts in short order. You'll be surprised at how many attempts are made and how many IPs are blacklisted. You don't need to blacklist them for too long before they move on to another host and someone else comes along.

Answer (score 0):

I've dropped sendmail 20 years ago, so I can't tell exactly how this works with sendmail, but my postfix tells me in the logs, who (user ID) added the mail to the queue. IF your spammer still manages to authenticate, you should find the account used this way.

You also might look at the `Received` headers in the spams (only look at the Received line(s) your own server writes; the rest might be fake) to learn more about your spammer and how he managed to trick your sendmail to accept his spam. Other headers addes by your server might help, too.

If you can't make sense of the logs or header lines yourself, please add them to your question for us to help out.